# Is there any difference between a QR code generated by an app and a screenshot of that QR code?

Tags: screenshot, qr-code

This is just a general question where I was wondering technically.

So, We have an app at school where once we can reserve books to borrow from the library. It keeps track of the count of books and the whole inventory. Once we "reserve" a book, a QR code is generated which we can show to the librarian and get the book. Also this QR code is valid only for sometime.

So, Anyway, Me and my friends decided to experiment with this. I reserved a book and sent a screenshot of the QR code to my friend to collect the book. But, the librarian on scanning the code knew something was amiss and asked to see his phone and discovered that it was a screenshot and refused to give him the book.

I am very curious to understand how did the librarian know it was a screenshot?
They have a dedicated QR/BAR code scanner device connected to their PC. But I thought that QR codes just encode some information. And using my phone's camera, I tested that the information encoded in the QR code on the app is the same as the information encoded in the screenshot of the QR code.

So, Technically, Do QR code scanners know/detect if the QR code is being shown on the app itself? Or is a clever bit of coding to ensure screenshots won't work and only the QR on the app works?

Example : When I have the QR code screen open on the app, it sends a request to the server to keep an eye out to the scanners? So, If I take a screenshot and try to scan it, The scanners refuse to process the QR because they didn't receive the information from servers to keep an eye out for the QR?

I know this is a huge question, But I was very curious on how one could make this functionality work :)

Comment: If this is an app, it might _not_ pre-generate the QR code, but instead generate one on the fly at the moment you open the reservation, and include (possibly hashed or encrypted) time stamp information in that. That way, screenshots can easily be detected, since they expire. You can test this just by taking two screenshots of the same reservation with a day in between and see if they still match. Usually such systems generate a code that stays valid for anywhere between 5 minutes and a day.

Comment: @Nyerguds I thought about this as well. So, I generated the QR code right when my friend reached the library and sent the screenshot to him then. It does have the date and time encoded in the code. But I thought that should still work since the screenshot's information will still be valid :)

Comment: Then the app might indeed keep the server updated on whether the currently generated code is opened in the app; it's possible it immediately invalidates the code at the moment you close it in the app. In that case, a screenshot should work as long as you keep the app and its QR code open on your side.

Comment: I mean, unless they're _really_ paranoid and added systems to detect you switching apps, preventing you from sending a screenshot without invalidating the code. I'm no mobile programmer, I dunno if that's possible, but I assume it is. And such a measure wouldn't interfere with the normal use case, where you just go to the app, open the code and let the librarian scan it.